# The #call function on my own classes

Tags: ruby

I know I can use the `#call` function on Proc objects, like so:

```
def you_called(object)
     object.call
end

a_proc = lambda {puts "I'm a Proc"}
you_called a_proc
```

But is there also a way to use the `#call` function on my own classes and if so how do I implement it?

My thinking goes along the lines like this:

```
class My_own_class
   def some_method
      puts "Hi from My_own_class#some_method"
   end
end

object = My_own_class.new
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Gerry Sure, I will edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, and here is how:

```
class Callable
  def self.class_method
    puts "I am a class method"
  end
  def instance_method
    puts "I am an instance method"
  end
end

Callable.method(:class_method).call
Callable.new.method(:instance_method).call
```